# Playing a sound from foreground service when a notification is recevied

Tags: android, firebase, android-service

I want to create a foreground service when the app receives a firebase notification. plays some sound.
I'm kind of new to android so I tried something but the app crashed.

**Foreground service**:

```
public class ListenerService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent notificationIntent =new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

        Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentText("FoneFinder")
                .setContentTitle("Keeping eye on your phone")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1,notification);
        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void playSound(){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(ListenerService.this,R.raw.a);
    }

}
```

**Firebase Messaging**:

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

       
        ListenerService listenerService = new ListenerService();
        listenerService.playSound();


    }

}
```

Error:

```
2020-12-20 21:33:19.850 8823-9091/com.example.fonefinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
    Process: com.example.fonefinder, PID: 8823
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:978)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:961)
        at com.example.fonefinder.ListenerService.playSound(ListenerService.java:41)
        at com.example.fonefinder.FirebaseMessaging.onMessageReceived(FirebaseMessaging.java:12)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:64)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:34)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:27)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:17)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.0:43)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

why does this happen? how can i fix it?

Comment: It's crashing because the Service's context is null. This is normal in your implementation, since you're creating it manually (new ListenerService()) and by doing it that way, the Android system can't attach it to a Context.

You should not create a new service in the "onMessageReceived" function. Instead, you should bind to you service (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binding) and use that instance to call your function.